# How to return type based on the object properties parameter with generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to return a promise if the user set true for async.

is seems typescript will always take the type from Create interface. how will I create a type that will be used to define the return type?

```
interface Create<T> {
  options: {
    async: boolean;
  };
  properties: T;
}

type Return<T extends Create<any>> = T["options"]["async"] extends true ? Promise<boolean> : boolean;

const create = <T>(value: Create<T>): Return<Create<T>> => {
  return true;
};

interface User {
  username: string;
  password: string;
}

// is not promise
create<User>({
  options: {
    async: true,
  },
  properties: {
    username: "",
    password: "",
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need one additional generic type parameter for the `async` option so that you can use it to infer the correct return type:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgThAhsCAeACnA9pOwCWEAzgDRQCSRAgkSAHYDGUEAHinQCZFQBGWWAGyR0AfFAC8UAN4AoKFBwEsdIgC5pURLUbrKNekwC+AbjlQw2XAWLrMOCHkJFTJmTNCRYCZBABKxAFcBYFQ9bSZWdi5efiFEUQkKanDmNghObmA4AOgAfig7AFt8IjQ+QWExdXK4ulMZDggGAUQEKAAzAMYlOigGbxQoDEsHa1Ik-UZUqO4ayoAKM3w6MADgdXgkFGH7R2IyMIMREhkASg2Bv0Dg0OSj+o9oAFVSuETZeQDXukRCiHUiFllgBzUzyMBaIgAdywcA4AKBdFBMlcDSaLTaDGUgKgXwcdjAaigLwc9QA9GTiUQQVBgAALaACfAoOCIARQAAGWRyHKgCCIQWA3GWmgK2GKpVUMixKmAfIAjIl+lsIPMpAowD0iVItAZ1NyIIYyBZdmN1Hi4ATuIZTmD5FAKQA9XJuClUmn0xnMhxszntNmlXn8wXC3qIGIVeJSmU4uAAJiVlzVGq16h14XU-oEpSN5hGeyJFqtUBtdvkTpdMjdLxp8Sgy0aLOKP0GczrADdWvhEDwhHzrkL62HcXR8MoFO1mMyGW8wFgiNSePgmaApY1mq1GRA5SVJgxqrFhKYY3K4ABmRMq5OKMcqNO6nT1u6MXMmqxOc2vYulszlsnOmQgA)

```ts
type Create<Properties, IsAsync extends boolean> = {
  options: { async: IsAsync };
  properties: Properties;
};

type CreateResult<IsAsync extends boolean> = IsAsync extends true ? Promise<boolean> : boolean;

declare function create <Properties, IsAsync extends boolean>(
  input: Create<Properties, IsAsync>,
): CreateResult<IsAsync>;

type User = {
  username: string;
  password: string;
};

declare const userProps: User;

// Using the literal `true` results in a Promise:
const r1 = create({ options: {async: true}, properties: userProps });
    //^? const r1: Promise<boolean>

// Using the literal `false` results in a boolean:
const r2 = create({ options: {async: false}, properties: userProps });
    //^? const r2: boolean

// Using an indeterminate boolean variable results in a union of either possibility:
declare let isAsync: boolean;
const r3 = create({ options: {async: isAsync}, properties: userProps });
    //^? const r3: boolean | Promise<boolean>
```

---

Update in response to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73215573/how-to-return-type-based-on-the-object-properties-parameter-with-generic-type/73215854?noredirect=1#comment129307451_73215854):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXzDigwQB4BJAZwEFKBPdeEADxNWEvgCMccIQoqAHwAKAFDx4WVAAdkGAFzwA3hMnwcM7HkpLl8KPXRKqtBmHgBfANxrJMmJpAxsIXfDQBrVDgDuqW0lLABoxAEoTGiMLFjYOeAwYZAQAfngABUcAWyxKEFIePgFheCVC-kFbMTAdDHgHJxcsN3gAXhU1ZDyYVCgskCUAckHQ+0NKXxwYYCGRsRsxMQB6JfgAVUppAHMEgAsECCwSGCgIeAADROTz+DhKZAgMTmkDDOzcgera24BGNoIiCQRPpNNpUO5lIZzEoriAQvVHDJnK5OJYwoF1CsAHopRYrdabVA7DD7eCHY6nC6IU55G53B5PKT4KDcXgVVAKL7guowABM-0IAiBIK0uHBeihxiQNLhwQRjRRVnRdng2Nxy1WG22Bnw0lAxxyvRIrKKgngADdYFgoFx+Lc3AznsyPKgxRpEEwjvsYPUcJRNlwsOS6JzQJBYAcQHVcmYpeVirYatzbgBmAWAkDAjSinQS6JKGPReENJFNFpojGSNViIA)

```ts
declare function create <IsAsync extends boolean>(
  input: {
    options: { async: IsAsync };
    properties: unknown;
  },
): IsAsync extends true ? Promise<boolean> : boolean;
```

Comment: It requires having only one generic type passed to the function union with the default to create an interface, do you think is it impossible to accomplish?

Comment: @Meslzy "..._only one generic type passed to the function_...": Sure — you actually don't **need** to create type aliases for any of those other structures because (1) they can be inlined, and (2) there's no [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) on the inner `properties` generic type that makes it useful (more narrow than `unknown`) within the function anyway. Only the one that's inferred when building the return type is needed. See the update in my answer.

Comment: `//^?` I didn't know about this! So cool! Also, nice answer +1. I knew this is possible but Typescript keeps on amazing me, how a value can determine a type and how a type can be inspected with a ternary operator, you know... 

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I can do. I don't like having to use a type assertion on the return, but I couldn't find a way around it.

```js
interface Create<T> {
  options: {
    async: boolean;
  };
  properties: T;
}

type Return<T> = T extends { options: { async: true } } ? Promise<boolean> : boolean;

const create = <T extends Create<any>>(value: T): Return<T> => {
  if (value.options.async === true) {
    return new Promise<boolean>((resolve) => resolve(true)) as Return<T>;
  }
  return true as Return<T>;
};

interface User {
  username: string;
  password: string;
}

create<Create<User>>({
  options: {
    async: true,
  },
  properties: {
    username: '',
    password: '',
  },
});
```

Comment: the idea i want is to only pass one generic interface is it possible somehow?

Comment: Typescript needs to know the value of `options.async`. So, either you add another type variable (as the other answer pointed out), or you pass the entire type of `value: T` as the Generic. Without it, there is not enough information to determine the type of `options.async`.